# Redirect after saving the model form in django cbv

Tags: python, django

what i am looking for is similar to Django admin action while adding a new item. When we add an item in Django admin, if a required item is not in foreign key, there is a link given there itself to add the required foreign key item, when clicking the link another pop up window appears and we can save the required item there and can go back to the main form and continue the job there. Similar to this, i have done everything except the redirect it back to the previously filled form. So how i can go back to there.

I have tried to redirect it back to the main form but it comes up without any previously filled data

My view is as follows views.py

```
class IsoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Iso
    form_class = IsoCreateForm
    template_name = 'forms/pefs_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data')
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use AJAX to create required object.

Then in your backend you return a JSONResponse with this object created you can update the form by adding your new object as an option.

[here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/27/how-to-return-json-encoded-response.html) you can see how to create a JSONResponse